# Intel Rapid Storage Technology (pre-OS) driver installation

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, installation, drivers, storage

My desktop machine is built on Gigabyte GA-Z87-UD3H and Gigabyte provides the latest driver for Intel Rapid Storage Technology (IRST), which I installed after installing the OS. Same goes for my Lenovo Thinkpad-T420. And for both machine, checking the controller device under the IDE ATA/ATAPI Controllers section in Device Manager I see the driver has been updated to the latest version.

- I set the SATA controller to AHCI from BIOS
- On the desktop machine I have one WD 2TB BLACK & one WD 3TB Green
- I don’t use RAID, & no chance of using in near future, but according to Intel IRST improves performance in single disk scenario too.

Now I have the following questions –

- What is the actual purpose of IRST (pre-OS install) driver that doesn’t get served with a post-OS driver that I installed? There must be some difference, otherwise there wouldn’t be a pre-OS version of the driver. Right?
- In the pre-OS procedure (loading the drivers at OS-installation time) after successfully completing the OS installation, do I need that post-OS driver? Because after installing from that one I got a quick launch icon that runs the IRST configuration application. Where do get that after installing the pre-OS driver?
- As it is “pre-OS”, when I load it at OS-installation time, does it updates anything at BIOS level or anywhere other than HDD? That’s because I’m going to dual boot Windows 7 with Windows 8.1, and after installing Windows 7 when I install Windows 8.1 & load the IRST driver for that, is there any chance of any “overwriting” or OS-incompatibility? In short, is there anything specific to follow while installing the second OS?

Comment: I believe you need a RST driver prior to installing the os only when there is a disk array created by the intel raid chip?  The normal install of any of the modern windows systems should have no requirement for that? So I am wondering if you tried without it?

Comment: @Psycogeek - I definitely tried without it. Now I'm willing to try with it. :)

Comment: I do not know enough to answer, but the software does have some cache stuff, that is what could make it faster by tiny bits when set correct even for singles. the pre-os drivers are usually simple and get the system operational.  the whole package includes the manager, and updated software that (like all packages) The latest driver matching the latest software so it all works together.